# Multiple Json objects in a json file to single proper json

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have multiple Json objects in each row in .json file as below. I want to add them to a array and form a single valid Json in the same file.

```
{"job": "developer"}
{"job": "taxi driver"}
{"job": "police"}
```

I want to convert the above each row json object data to single valid json in the file.

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "job": "developer"
    },
    {
      "job": "taxi driver"
    },
    {
      "job": "police"
    }
  ]
}
```

**The file size is 1.1 GB. Multiple files are in the directory with the same content and all of them need to be converted.**

Please suggest approach in python.

Tried this

```
import json
data = {'records': []}

with open("test.json", 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        data['records'].append(json.loads(line))
        
print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: *Please suggest approach in python* tells me you haven't tried to solve this at all, but are looking for someone to write the solution for you

Comment: Hi Nivis, Tried this in Java but it is taking 5 min for converting the data of 70 MB file. we are looking at 1000 files with huge data.

Comment: Sounds like a good Java question. Why not edit your question to include your java attempt and see if someone can help you find why it's so slow? I don't think a language swap is your best bet here

Comment: You said "tried this".  And what happened?  As a side note, if the format is exactly like that, you can make it a simple text editor operation, by adding a "," at the end of each line.

Comment: What's wrong with the code you posted? Seems fine to me.

Comment: *"I want to add them to a array and form a single valid Json in the same file"* - Why? And why did whoever created it as it is create it as it is?

Comment: I probably would use `jq -s '{Records: .}' test.json > result.json` instead of Python. (Though with 1.1GB of data, a streaming version might be necessary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that's the exact format, you can do this without actually decoding and re-encoding the lines:

```
prefix = '{"Records":['
for line in open('x.json'):
    print(prefix, line, end='')
    prefix = ","
print(']}')
```

Output:

```
timr@Tims-NUC:~/src$ python x.py | jq
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "job": "developer"
    },
    {
      "job": "taxi driver"
    },
    {
      "job": "police"
    }
  ]
}
```

### Followup

Let's assume your input pseudo-JSON files are in a folder called "input" and you want the results written to files of the same name in a folder called "output".  Then something like this would work:

```
import glob

def convertone(fin, fout):
    outgo = open(fout, 'w')
    prefix = '{"Records":['
    for line in open(fin):
        print(prefix, line, end='', file=outgo)
        prefix = ","
    print(']}', file=outgo)

for name in glob.glob("input/*.json"):
    convertone(name, name.replace('input','output'))
```

You could also use `os.listdir` there.

Comment: elegant imperative code like this really gives me the "warm and fuzzies"

Comment: How to write the output to a file here?

Comment: Well, from a command line one at a time you could use `> out.json`, but if you're doing this in code in a loop, then you would use the `file=` parameter of `print`.